# Using ASM in C++

Tags: c++, assembly

I am using the following code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    __asm{ 
           "MOV EAX, DMSN[0]";
           "LEA EBX, DMSN[0]";
           "CALL EBX";
         };
    return 0;
}
```

`MOV EAX` and `LEA EBX`, will later contain two different arrays.
But as for the example they will contain the same.

I am using the following:

```
const BYTE DMSN[694]={blah, blah, blah};
```

But i am turning up with these erros:

```
1>c:\users\1337\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test2\test2\test2.cpp(49): error     C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found 'bad token'
1>c:\users\1337\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test2\test2\test2.cpp(50): error     C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found 'bad token'
1>c:\users\1337\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test2\test2\test2.cpp(51): error     C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found 'bad token'**strong text**
```

What is wrong?

Comment: If you're new to C++, you probably don't want to be messing with inline assembly as the very first thing.

Comment: remove "" from assembly lines.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is faulty,  use it like this:-

```
 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
      _asm{ 
           mov eax, DMSN[0]
           lea ebx, DMSN[0]
           call ebx
          }
        return 0;
    }
```

for VS based compiler.

Answer (score 1):

if dmsn is array, you dont have to put [0] to access first element

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    __asm{ 
           mov eax, DMSN
           lea ebx, DMSN
           call ebx
         };
    return 0;
}
```

mov instruction will automatically check for the operand sizes and will take first 32 bits into register(eax)  and 32 bit effective address to register(ebx)

VC++ 2010 express